# How to pass command line arguments along with perl modules using perl?

Tags: perl

---

I treid one of my previous example to pass input and output files via command line arguments using perl?

Previous example:

[[Is it possible to add the file out in the File::Find::Rule using perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42500436/is-it-possible-to-add-the-file-out-in-the-filefindrule-using-perl][1])

code which i tried to add input and output file as command line arguments:(`generate.pl`).I got struck how to include command line arguments to read and copy the files along with perl modules.

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use CGI qw(:all);
#generate the user file arguments
use Getopt::Long 'GetOptions';
use File::Path       qw( make_path );
use File::Copy  qw( copy move);
use File::Find::Rule qw( );
GetOptions(
    'prjroot=s' => \my $input_dir,
    'outdir=s'  => \my $output_dir,
); 
my %created;
for my $in (
   File::Find::Rule
   ->file()
   ->name(qr/^[^.].*\.yfg$/)
   ->in($input_dir)
) {
   my $match_file = substr($in, length($input_dir) + 1); 
   my ($match_dir) = $match_file =~ m{^(.*)/} ? $1 : '.';
   my $out_dir = $output_dir . '/' . $match_dir;
   my $out     = $output_dir . '/' . $match_file;
   make_path($out_dir) if !$created{$out_dir}++;
   copy($in, $out);
}
```

Error occured:

```
./generate.pl: line 1: use: command not found
./generate.pl: line 2: use: command not found
./generate.pl: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./generate.pl: line 3: `use CGI qw(:all);'
```

perl execution should be as follows:

I should copy the contents from one directory to another directory along with perl modulES(I.E File::Find::Rule)

```
./generate.pl -prjroot "/home/bharat/DATA" -outdir "/home/bharat/DATA1"
```

Help me fix my issues .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss the perl comment in the first line:

```
#!<path_to_perl>/perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use CGI qw(:all);
#generate the user file arguments
.....
```

Your program will also work if you call it with the perl Interpreter in front of your command:

```
perl ./generate.pl -prjroot "/home/bharat/DATA" -outdir "/home/bharat/DATA1"
```

Answer (score 1):

You've already seen what the problem is. But I'll just add that [perldoc perldiag](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html) gives pretty good explanations for any error message you get from Perl. In this case, searching for "command not found" would give you this:

> **%s: Command not found**
>
> (A) You've accidentally run your script through csh or another shell instead of Perl. Check the #! line, or manually feed your script into Perl yourself. The #! line at the top of your file could look like
>
> ```
> #!/usr/bin/perl -w
> ```

And that's particularly impressive, given that this  error isn't actually generated by Perl - but by your shell.